# Rewriting a Hibernate SessionFactory Query with EntityManger using JPA2 involving Date restrictions

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, entitymanager

I have a query I would write in older Hibernate (utilising the `SessionFactory` bean). However, I have shifted to Spring Boot and am now utilizing the JPA 2 which is essentially seems like a layer of abstraction over Hibernate. Could anyone guide me on as to how to add restrictions? I believe I will now have to use the `EntityManager` bean with JPA. Here is the older query.

```
@Override
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public List<Party> queryPartiesBetweenDates(Date startDate, Date endDate, String sortBy, Integer count) {
    Criteria criteria = getCurrentSession().createCriteria(Party.class);
    if (startDate != null) {
        criteria.add(Restrictions.ge("startDate", startDate));
    }
    if (endDate != null) {
        criteria.add(Restrictions.lt("endDate", endDate));
    }
    if (count != null) {
        criteria.setMaxResults(count);
    }
    if (sortBy == null || !sortBy.equals("distance")) {
        criteria.addOrder(Order.asc("startDate"));
    }
    return criteria.list();
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: this will help. https://www.jumpingbean.co.za/blogs/jpa2-criteria-api

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The CriteriaBuilder is quite a bit more verbose than the native hibernate Restriction API, the primary reason is that it is fully typed when you use the MetaModel, which means the code will not compile if the type or name of a column causing a query to be invalid.
Here is an example that does not use the generated MetaModel classes, and mostly resembles the old Hibernate code.

```
EntityManager em = emf.createEntityManager(); // or injected

CriteriaBuilder cb = em.getCriteriaBuilder();
CriteriaQuery<Party> query = cb.createQuery(Party.class);
Root<Party> partyRoot = query.from(Party.class);
query.select(partyRoot);

Predicate predicate = null;
Path<Date> startDatePath = partyRoot.<Date>get("startDate");
if (startDate != null) {
    predicate = cb.greaterThanOrEqualTo(startDatePath, startDate);
}
if (endDate != null) {
    Predicate additionalPredicate = cb.lessThanOrEqualTo(partyRoot.<Date>get("endDate"), startDate);
    if (predicate == null) {
        predicate = additionalPredicate;
    } else {
        predicate = cb.and(predicate, additionalPredicate);
    }
}
query.where(predicate);

if (sortBy == null || !sortBy.equals("distance")) {
    query.orderBy(cb.asc(startDatePath));
}

return em.createQuery(query).setMaxResults(count).getResultList();
```

If you have many Predicates, it may be a good idea to add them to a list, or create a utility method for handling them.

Comment: I liked how you sort of bypassed the use of metamodal classes. Can mostly every query be written without the metamodal classes this way?

Comment: You don't need the static meta model, as long as you know the field name. Some times you will have to cast the return from Root.get() , because ```Path```and ```Expression``` are very general, and you may need to know that the field references a collection element so you can use it for join syntax. However the best option is to generate the (static) meta model as part you build (Annotation processing) this will generate a class  named ```Party_```so you can just use```Party_.startDate```to get the Path, and then it is completely type safe.